# RestKit mapping object without object class

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I have this issue, that i'm mapping all object properly, but the properties that are inside the root object, for some reason I cannot map.

This is the JSON:

```
{
  "responseError": null,
  "responseIsRegisteredServices": {
    "registeredToServiceAntiVirus": true,
    "registeredToServiceCloud": true,
    "registeredToServiceMusic": true,
    "registeredToServiceSong": true,
    "registeredToServiceTv": true
  },
  "responseRegisteredServicesCloud": null,
  "responseRegisteredServicesMusic": [
    {
      "ID": null,
      "Name": null,
      "AlbumPic": "110_110.png",
      "ArtistName": "Rihanna"
    },
    {
      "ID": null,
      "Name": null,
      "AlbumPic": "110_110.png",
      "ArtistName": "Rihanna"
    },
    {
      "ID": null,
      "Name": null,
      "AlbumPic": "110_110.png",
      "ArtistName": "Steve Angello"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the `RegisteredServices` class:

```
@interface RegisteredServices : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) ResponseError *responseError;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *registeredToServiceAntiVirus;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *registeredToServiceCloud;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *registeredToServiceMusic;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *registeredToServiceSong;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *registeredToServiceTv;
@property (nonatomic) CloudServices *responseRegisteredServicesCloud;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *responseRegisteredServicesMusix;
@end
```

This is the 'CloudServices' class:

```
@interface CloudServices : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *capacityType;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *currentCapacity;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *lastBackupDate;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *percentage;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *totalCapacity;
@end
```

This is the 'MusicServices' class:

```
@interface MusicServices : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *idNum;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *albumPic;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *artistName;
@end
```

This is the mapping itself:

```
RKObjectMapping *musixMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MusicServices class]];

[musicMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"ID" : @"idNum",
                                                    @"Name" : @"name",
                                                    @"AlbumPic" : @"albumPic",
                                                    @"ArtistName" : @"artistName" }];

RKObjectMapping *cloudMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CloudServices class]];

[cloudMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"capacityType": @"capacityType",
                                                   @"currentCapacity": @"currentCapacity",
                                                   @"lastBackupDate": @"lastBackupDate",
                                                   @"percentage": @"percentage",
                                                   @"totalCapacity": @"totalCapacity" }];

RKObjectMapping *registeredServicesMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RegisteredServices class]];

[registeredServicesMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"registeredToServiceAntiVirus" : @"registeredToServiceAntiVirus",
                                                                 @"registeredToServiceCloud" : @"registeredToServiceCloud",
                                                                 @"registeredToServiceMusic" : @"registeredToServiceMusic",
                                                                 @"registeredToServiceSong" : @"registeredToServiceSong",
                                                                 @"registeredToServiceTv" : @"registeredToServiceTv", }];

[registeredServicesMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"responseRegisteredServicesMusic" mapping:musixMapping];

[registeredServicesMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"responseError"
                                                                                          toKeyPath:@"responseError"
                                                                                        withMapping:errorMapping]];

[registeredServicesMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"responseRegisteredServicesCloud"
                                                                                          toKeyPath:@"responseRegisteredServicesCloud"
                                                                                        withMapping:cloudMapping]];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:registeredServicesMapping
                                                                                                    method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                               pathPattern:@"registeredServices"
                                                                                                   keyPath:nil
                                                                                               statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];
```

Can't figure out what seems to be the problem. When I add `responseIsRegisteredServices` into the `keyPath:` of the `RKResponseDescriptor` than the `MusicServices` array is null.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've found the answer, in this line:

```
[registeredServicesMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"registeredToServiceAntiVirus" : @"registeredToServiceAntiVirus",
                                                                 @"registeredToServiceCloud" : @"registeredToServiceCloud",
                                                                 @"registeredToServiceMusic" : @"registeredToServiceMusic",
                                                                 @"registeredToServiceSong" : @"registeredToServiceSong",
                                                                 @"registeredToServiceTv" : @"registeredToServiceTv", }];
```

I needed to change it from `registeredToServiceAntiVirus` to `responseIsRegisteredServices .registeredToServiceAntiVirus` and than it worked perfectly. This is how it looks:

```
[registeredServicesMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"responseIsRegisteredServices.registeredToServiceAntiVirus" : @"registeredToServiceAntiVirus",
                                                                 @"responseIsRegisteredServices.registeredToServiceCloud" : @"registeredToServiceCloud",
                                                                 @"responseIsRegisteredServices.registeredToServiceMusic" : @"registeredToServiceMusic",
                                                                 @"responseIsRegisteredServices.registeredToServiceSong" : @"registeredToServiceSong",
                                                                 @"responseIsRegisteredServices.registeredToServiceTv" : @"registeredToServiceTv", }];
```

Enjoy.